# Router as NAS fileserver

Tags: router, ethernet

I have a Router with USB hard drive sharing capabilities...

but I want to replace it.

There's a good chance the replacement router won't have USB sharing capabilities...

Can I just disable the antenna and plug the old router into the new one and still be able to use it as a file server visible to the other devices plugged into the new router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-depending on your brand and model- yes,

Most routers will allow you to disable dhcp and act as a bridge or access point.
This will allow your old router to just act as a normal network device with file sharing.